# Multi NOT IN Sql statements

Tags: mysql

I had a situation where I had to combine three files and only show results on rows that matched. That works!!
Now I have a situation where I have to take the base which contains over 2,222,321 codes and subtract the run that matched and display the differences

The first file is matching on SourceID and contains the 2,222,321 entries
The second file is output from the first run  - it only contains 4354 rows of matching data

```
SELECT b.Primary,
       a.Active,
       a.ModuleID,
       b.DefinitionStatusID,
       b.LanguageCode, 
       a.TypeID, 
       b.Term,
       a.Primary,
       b.Destination,
       b.RelationshipGroup,
       b.ConceptID
FROM  mstr_First_sct2_relationship_full_us100124 a, mstr_SOBC_Matching b 
where b.Primary Not in (a.SourceID) and
      b.Primary Not in (b.ConceptID) and 
      a.Active = '1'
```

End result would only pull records where Primary is not equal to Source or Concept which are in different files.

Comment: Files? Do you mean tables?

Comment: Is the query in your question the query that is returning the matches, or is this what you tried and it isn't working? (From the question, it's not clear what conditions are considered a match.)

Comment: Yes I mean tables  - Sorry

Comment: If one of the answers worked for you, please consider accepting it. If not, please provide clarification so we can help or post your own answer if you figured it out yourself. (If you post your own answer, there is a waiting period before StackOverflow will allow you to accept it, but you will be allowed to.)

Answer (score 0):

Try Using **Not Exist**

```
SELECT b.Primary,
       a.Active,
       a.ModuleID,
       b.DefinitionStatusID,
       b.LanguageCode, 
       a.TypeID, 
       b.Term,
       a.Primary,
       b.Destination,
       b.RelationshipGroup,
       b.ConceptID
FROM  mstr_First_sct2_relationship_full_us100124 a
WHERE NOT EXIST
(
  SELECT * FROM mstr_SOBC_Matching b 
  WHERE b.Primary = a.SourceID AND
        b.Primary IN (b.ConceptID) AND
        a.Active = '1' 

)
```

Comment: Won't `b.Primary = b.ConceptID` only check the current row?

Comment: It will check only current row

Comment: Given that the OP tried to call `NOT IN (b.ConceptID)`, I'm guessing they want to compare against all `b.ConceptID`s. ...The table structure probably leaves much to be desired.

Comment: I have Updated this now

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about efficiency, but it works:

```
SELECT *
FROM mstr_First_sct2_relationship_full_us100124 a, mstr_SOBC_Matching b
WHERE b.PrimaryID NOT IN (SELECT SourceID
                          FROM mstr_First_sct2_relationship_full_us100124
                          WHERE Active = '1'
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT ConceptID
                          FROM mstr_SOBC_Matching
                         );
```

SQL Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9dbb/6/0

You have no `JOIN` condition between the two tables, by the way. Maybe you meant to `JOIN` on `Primary`?